# Resistor, Inductor or something else?

Tags: identification, components, graphics

[image: side][image]I'm trying to identify a component marked simply as "R". There are two of these on a graphics card I am trying to fix that has a power issue. Thanks for any help...[image: R2]

Comment: Refdes are L13 and L15 so apparently inductors : look like ferrite beads for RF attenuation. I expect they measure below 0.1 ohm at DC?

Comment: What is the size of that part?

Comment: size of the part is about 6-7mm. Measurement is about 0.1 ohm for one but seems shorted for the "yellow R." Not sure if that could happen though.

Comment: You'd have to pull it off the board to see if it's really shorted or find what it is

Comment: What are all the dimensions *exactly* w x l x h

Comment: Whatever it is, it doesn't look bad , I'd say it has a 2x2mm conductor with 0 Ohms + 1nH next to a 5 mOhm resistor

Comment: Item has been removed, tested and is shorted out. Dimensions : 2x2x6 mm. I have included a side view of the component.

Comment: Thanks for all comments!